# Does Skype work for the Guest login?

Tags: skype, guest-account

Skype works fine when I launch it on my Login.  When I switch to the Guest login, though, Skype launches but does not connect after 90 seconds.  Does it eventually connect if I give it more time, or is there some architectural obstacle that prevents using it as Guest?

Answer (score 2):

You say that you 'switch' to the Guest login. Are you using fast user switching and leaving Skype running on your other account? It may not be a problem with the Guest account, but with trying to run multiple instances of Skype on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, I mean fast user switching.  I am not running Skype deliberately in my primary account, but perhaps it is using some resource behind the scenes, doing a background login or some such.

Comment: I can run skype in my main admin login, and my guest login happily - but that's on 10.6.5 and the skype 5 beta - maybe upgrading to the skype beta would fix it?

Comment: @glenstorey, I will try again now that 10.6.8 is out.

Comment: It may depend on your firewall settings. I know from experience that Skype will bind to port 80 if that is the only path through the firewall -- it can't do this on two separate user accounts. Presumably it will work on two separate accounts if it can bind to different ports.